# Uncaught ReferenceError : Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to make a survey, and with each click, assign a variable a certain phrase. Then display it in the `div` when I click  `span#display` .
I get the "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" when I run this code:

```
var a = "none chosen";
function companyPicka()
            {
                a= "I love Valve";
            } 
            function companyPickb()
            {
                a= "I love Bethesda";
            } 
            function companyPickc()
            {
                a= "I love EA";
            } 
            function companyPickd()
            {
                a= "I love Ubisoft";
            } 
            function companyPicke()
            {
                a= "I play terrible NES, SNES games";
            } 
            function companyPickf()
            {
                a= "I like something that's so underground I wouldn't expect  you to know it";
            }
function display()
            {
                document.getElementById("display") = "a+''+b+''+c+''+d+''+e+''+f+''+g+''+h";
            }


<div>
                <span onclick="companyPicka(); this.style.border='inset';">
                Valve &#60;3</span> 
                <span onclick="companyPickb(); this.style.border='inset';"> 
                Bethesda :\ </span>
                <span onclick="companyPickc(); this.style.border='inset';">
                EA </span>
                <span onclick="companyPickd(); this.style.border='inset';"> 
                Ubisoft </span>
                <span onclick="companyPicke(); this.style.border='inset';">
                LJN</span>
                <span onclick="companyPickf(); this.style.border='inset';">
                Other</span>
            </div>

<span onclick="display();"> See Results </span>
            <div id="display">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following line is wrong:

```
document.getElementById("display") = "a+''+b+''+c+''+d+''+e+''+f+''+g+''+h";
```

You can't assign a string directly to an HTML element. One way to set the element's content is with `.innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "something";
```

Note also that the right-hand side of your expression is a string containing the actual text `a+''+b+''+c+''+d+''+e+''+f+''+g+''+h` - that is, the character "a" then the character "+", then two apostrophes, etc. It is not an expression concatenating the variables a, b, c, etc. (not that your code as shown has variables for b, c, d, etc). If you remove the surrounding double-quotes it would be an expression concatenating the variables.

Having a different function for every option is a very messy way to code this type of thing. You may like to try something like the following (could be further tidied, but I don't want to overload you with too much information all at once):

```
var phrases = {
      a : "I love Valve",
      b : "I love Bethesda",
      c : "I love EA",
      d : "I love Ubisoft",
      e : "I play terrible NES, SNES games",
      f : "I like something that's so underground I wouldn't expect  you to know it"
    },
    currentPhrase = "none selected";

function companyPick(which) {
   currentPhrase = phrases[which] || "none selected";
}

function display() {
   document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = currentPhrase;
}

<div>
  <span onclick="companyPick('a'); this.style.border='inset';">
  Valve &#60;3</span> 
  <span onclick="companyPick('b'); this.style.border='inset';"> 
  Bethesda :\ </span>
  <span onclick="companyPick('c'); this.style.border='inset';">
  EA </span>
  <span onclick="companyPick('d'); this.style.border='inset';"> 
  Ubisoft </span>
  <span onclick="companyPick('e'); this.style.border='inset';">
  LJN</span>
  <span onclick="companyPick('f'); this.style.border='inset';">
  Other</span>
</div>

<span onclick="display();"> See Results </span>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: you even showed him how to make it less complicated to write +1. |||

whats abut passing `this` to `companyPick` too and set the border in the function?

Comment: Thanks @micha. It would be better to associate a single click handler with the containing div instead of having one on every span, then give each span an id or data-company attribute or something which the click handler could retrieve to select the appropriate phrase from. And yes, put the style thing in the function. But as I said in my answer, I didn't want to get too carried away with new information all at once. Also, now that I think about it I suspect the intention is to allow more than one option to be selected at a time - easy to do, but getting way beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 3):

This line is incorrect:

```
document.getElementById("display") = "a+''+b+''+c+''+d+''+e+''+f+''+g+''+h";
```

use this:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = a+''+b+''+c+''+d+''+e+''+f+''+g+''+h;
```

**Edit:**

Actually this makes no scene: `a+''+b+''+c+''+d+''+e+''+f+''+g+''+h`

It is the same like this: `a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h`

Comment: but there is no space in between ;)